# Extract all words inside a random filled crossword table

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In a crossword table, assuming it is for mobile devices and unlike regular crosswords which you can find words in 8 straight directions, is there any standard algorithm to find all words based on a dictionary?

In my table, you can build a word by swiping on the letters in all directions as long as your gesture is continuous (the move is continuous and you don’t release your touch from the screen) on the screen and does not go back on a touched word from the last move.

There is a similar app [Wordament](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.wordament&hl=en). In the [Wordament](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.wordament&hl=en) application, it knows all possible words from the start of the level and it shows you the hidden words. If I start to iterate through all e.g. 2-letter words and compare to the touched letters then for example for a list of 1000 2-letter words in a 5x5 table the total iterations will be around 145k. Assume that we have anything from 2-letter up to 15-letter words.

To list all possible words, first I start by first cell (I have made a 2d char array to store letters), if the dictionary’s first word’s first letter equals to this cell then I move to the next char of the first word of dictionary and move to next cell in the array and do this for all characters of the first word of dictionary against all letters inside the array. Is this approach even correct?!
Is there any efficient way of guessing all possible words in a random filled table with characters?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The proposed algorithm sounds right. Consider removing the words already matched from the comparing table, if it makes sense. Also, maybe it would be more efficient if, instead of iterating through all same-length words, you have your dictionary sorted and checking all any-length words for the each sequence

Comment: Personally, I'd use load all the words into a "Character Tree" and search against that.

Comment: As a point of interest, a *crossword* is a different sort of puzzle than you're describing.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossword

Answer (score 0):

My personal take on fast lookups for words would be a char tree. Fast and minimal memory footprint, but have to pre-load it (or somehow serialise it pre-filled)

```
class CharTree {

    public class TreeNode {
        public bool HasChildren { get { return Children.Count > 0; } }

        public Dictionary<char, TreeNode> Children = new Dictionary<char, TreeNode>();

        public TreeNode this[char idx] {
            get { return Children[idx]; }
            set { Children[idx] = value; }
        }
    }

    protected TreeNode Root;

    public void AddChars(string line) {

        if (Root == null) Root = new TreeNode();

        var currentNode = Root;

        foreach(var letter in line) {
            if (!currentNode.Children.ContainsKey(letter))
                currentNode.Children.Add(letter, new TreeNode());
        }
    }

    public string Validate( string line ) {


        var currentNode = Root;

        if (currentNode == null) return null;

        var result = "";

        foreach ( var letter in line ) {
            currentNode = currentNode[letter];

            if (currentNode == null) break;

            result += letter;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

How you build the 'lines' are up to you. You'll still have to iterate around your 2D array using whatever rules your players are bound by.

Comment: Thanks i will try this and send feedback